# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ActivityInstances' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to insert a new ActivityInstance, I am not setting the ID, but entity framework is attempting to insert an ID anyway.

The model creation and save command:

```
        var ai = new ActivityInstance
        {
            ActivityId = 1,
            LocationId = 1,
            BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
            ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        DbContext.ActivityInstances.Add(activityInstance);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The Model

```
public class ActivityInstance : IBusinessObject, IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string TargetId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? DurableInstanceWorkflowId { get; set; }
    public int? TriggeredById { get; set; }
    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual MsdsDataValidation MsdsDataValidation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResultsTransmittalQuestionAnswer> ActivityQuestionAnswers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ResultsTransmittalContact> ResultsTransmittalContacts { get; set; }
    public virtual Target Target { get; set; }
    public virtual CorrectiveActionPlan CorrectiveActionPlans { get; set; }
    public virtual FmVisit FmVisit { get; set; }
    public virtual AcknowledgeReport AcknowledgeReport { get; set; }
    public virtual SlCap SlCap { get; set; }
    public virtual FmVisitStudentRecordReview FmVisitStudentRecordReview { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActivityInstanceReminder> ActivityInstanceReminders { get; set; } 
   // public virtual InstancesTable Instances { get; set; }
}
```

The Mapping

```
    public ActivityInstanceMap()
    {
        ToTable("ActivityInstances");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);

        Property(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.LocationId);
        Property(t => t.TargetId);
        Property(t => t.ActivityId);
        Property(t => t.BeginDate);
        Property(t => t.ExpirationDate);
        Property(t => t.DurableInstanceWorkflowId);
        Property(t => t.TriggeredById);

        HasOptional(x => x.Target)
            .WithMany(x => x.ActivityInstances)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TargetId);

        HasRequired(t => t.Activity)
            .WithMany(t => t.ActivityInstances)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ActivityId);

        HasRequired(t => t.Location)
            .WithMany(t => t.ActivityInstances)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.LocationId);

        HasOptional(t => t.AcknowledgeReport)
            .WithRequired(t => t.ActivityInstance);

    }
```

The table design

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityInstances]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [DurableInstanceWorkflowId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [TargetId] NVARCHAR(128) NULL,
    [LocationId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ActivityId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [BeginDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [ExpirationDate] DATETIME NULL,
    [TriggeredById] INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [Pk_ActivityInstances_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] Asc), 
    CONSTRAINT [Fk_ActivityInstances_ToLocations] FOREIGN KEY ([LocationId]) REFERENCES dbo.Locations([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [Fk_ActivityInstances_ToActivities] FOREIGN KEY ([ActivityId]) REFERENCES dbo.Activities([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FkInstanceTriggeredInstance] FOREIGN KEY ([TriggeredById]) REFERENCES dbo.ActivityInstances([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [Fk_ActivityInstances_ToDurableWorkflowInstance] FOREIGN KEY ([DurableInstanceWorkflowId]) REFERENCES [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].InstancesTable([Id])
)
```

And this is what I am getting in my Output window.  The Id value is the default integer 0.

```
 INSERT [dbo].[ActivityInstances]([Id], [LocationId], [TargetId], [ActivityId], [BeginDate], [ExpirationDate], [DurableInstanceWorkflowId], [TriggeredById])
    VALUES (@0, @1, NULL, @2, @3, @4, NULL, NULL)
```

**UPDATE**
I modified the ActivityInstance model with the first suggested answer which has led me toward the actual issue, though I still have not solved it.  That recommendation was to modify the ActivityInstance model setting the below on id

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

Now I am getting the error:

> A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'.

I am looking at the optional one to one relationship currently.  Acknowledge report table is:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AcknowledgeReports]
(
    [ActivityInstanceId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AcknowledgeReportsId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ActivityInstanceId] ASC)
)

AcknowledgeReport model

```
public class AcknowledgeReport : IActivityInstance
{
    public int ActivityInstanceId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Report> Reports { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityInstance ActivityInstance { get; set; }

}
```

And AcknowledgeReport mapping

```
    public AcknowledgeReportMap()
    {
        ToTable("AcknowledgeReports");
        HasKey(t => t.ActivityInstanceId);

        Property(t => t.ActivityInstanceId);


        // Relationships


    }
```

Comment: I am uncertain which duplicate choose from the related column on the right... Did you search anything about this error before?

Comment: Yes, I have been through EVERY similar post and eliminated all the possible solutions.  This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bhmahler's suggestion above I finally started looking into every relationship.  One of the other programmers added the MsdsDataValidation and when they mapped the relationship they configured it backward.  So in the MsdsDataValidationMap he had

```
            HasOptional(t => t.ActivityInstance)
            .WithRequired(t => t.MsdsDataValidation);
```

and should have had

```
            HasRequired(t => t.ActivityInstance)
            .WithOptional(t => t.MsdsDataValidation);
```

The back of his head will be smacked.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the attributes to let it know that it is database generated

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Bhmahler. This did not solve the problem but led me to a different error message. I updated the original question with the new information and am still poking at the issue and reading similar threads.